# How to catch Exceptions from System.Data namespace?

Tags: entity-framework, exception

I started using Entity Framework 4.3.1 with code first approach.

I want to avoid application crash when database server is shut down or unavailable catching specific exceptions.
Imagine this short sample piece of code:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
     var people = new People();
     db.People.AddObject(people);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When server is shut down, I receive ProviderIncompatibleException.
If I try to modify code catching ProviderIncompatibleException like this

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
     try
     {
         var people = new People();
         db.People.AddObject(people);
         db.SaveChanges();
     }
     catch(ProviderIncopatibleException)
     {
     }
}
```

I receive compiler error "The type caught or thrown must be derived from System.Exception".
How can I catch most specific Exception using Entity framework?
Thank you for help.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.providerincompatibleexception.aspx it derives from System.Exception. Have you tried using whole class path: `System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException`?

Comment: There's a typo in the name: ProviderInco-patibleException`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek You're right. I didn´t referenced System.Data assembly

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in the class name - you missed out an 'm' in Incompatible.

Try again with `ProviderIncompatibleException`